# find word only in single braces using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like

```
text= '{username} joined {servername} {{anytext}} '
```

and a simple regex code

```
print(re.findall('{([^{}]*)}', text))

#output
['username', 'servername', 'anytext']
```

Where `anytext` is inside double braces but it is also validating by the regex. I mean, the regex should only find word in single braces and ignore double braces.

Please help me to do this happen.

Comment: While [edit]s to the question to provide clarification and/or additional information are encouraged, edits which change the question sufficiently to invalidate an already posted answer are not permitted. In fact, the consensus is that any user with [edit privileges](/help/privileges/edit) should revert such edits. I have done so here. Please note that this doesn't prevent you from completely changing a question prior to any answers being posted. If you desire, you're welcome to post a [new question](/questions/ask) on your new issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the string against the regular expression

```
(?<!{{)(?<={)[^{}]*?(?=})(?!}})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kpdmAz/1)

As seen, there are two matches:

```
'{username} joined {servername} {{anytext}}'
  ^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<!{{)  # a negative lookbehind asserts the current location
         # in the string is not preceded by '{{' 
(?<={)   # a positive lookbehind asserts the current location
         # in the string is preceded by '{' 
[^{}]*?  # match zero or more characters other than '{' and '}'
(?=})    # a positive lookahead asserts the current location
         # in the string is followed by '}' 
(?!}})   # a negative lookahead asserts the current location
         # in the string is not followed by '}}'
```

If desired, the negative lookarounds could be embedded in the positive ones:

```
(?<=(?<!{{){)[^{}]*?(?=}(?!}))
```

---

The string could first be tested to have balanced braces by matching it against the following regular expression.

```
^[^{}]*(?:(?:{[^{}]*}|{{[^{}]*}})[^{}]*)*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gu00RD/1)

Hover the cursor over each part of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you *only* expect either `{...}` or `{{...}}` we can use the following `re.findall` trick:

```py
text = '{username} joined {servername} {{anytext}}'
matches = [x for x in re.findall(r'\{\{.*?\}\}|\{(.*?)\}', text) if x]
print(matches)  # ['username', 'servername']
```

The trick here is to match `{{...}}` first in the alternation followed by `{...}`, while only capturing the second single bracket version.  We filter off the empty matches, leaving behind the matches we want.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine but if  I want something more like- "{username} joined {servername} {{anytext {word} yes}}" in this text the {word} should also validate. Plz say If I can do this

Comment: Gliese, for that string `username`, `servername` and  `{{anytext {word} yes}}` would be matched but only the first two would be captured. With Tim's technique, no attention is paid to strings that are matched but not captured.

Comment: Yup @CarySwoveland I got that and the another answer is perfect